# What is "Using network 'develop'" in truffle?

Tags: blockchain, truffle, go-ethereum

When i install pet-shop in truffle:

```
truffle(develop)> migrate
Using network 'develop'.
Network up to date.
truffle(develop)> test
Using network 'develop'.
0 passing (0ms)
```

Can you tell me what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just meaning that you have migrate to a network with name "develop".
You'd probably better specify what are you intended to do here and add you truffle.js